# Why I can still type in the console while I don't call readLine()?

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I wanted to make a demo of reading input from console then using `JOptionPane`. If I first type `br.readLine()` then use `JOption...` the input dialog is not showing and I can still write in the console like somebody would wait for it... I want input dialog to show up.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Kalkulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Type number");
            int liczba1 = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
            br.close();
            int liczba2 = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type number"));
            System.out.println(liczba1 + liczba2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because `System.in` is a stream. When you type, you *provide* data. That data is stored in some kind of queue.

When one calls `br.readLine`, a part of the queue is read out (and sometimes blocks until data is provided)...

Closing a stream simply means that you recycle some resources (like for instance mark a file again as available). Now a console keeps accepting data. You only won't read it anymore.

It is up to the console program (`bash`, `sh`, `cmd.exe`,...) to handle the fact that a user enters data. A console program then redirects the entered values to `System.in`. Java has no control over that program...

Comment: Can I make it behave like I wanted to?

Comment: @Yoda you can't read from the console after you have closed it.

Comment: @Yoda: Probably not, because it is up to the console application to decide on this (`bash`, `sh`,... in Linux `cmd.exe` in Windows). They decide when one can "enter" data. However once you've closed the stream. You prevent your java program to read data further....

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't want to read from console... I want to InputDialaiog to show up.

Comment: @Yoda It works fine for me when I run it with Java 8.  Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The code works indeed. Yoda wants to add an additional feature: blocking the user from entering input (at some point in the program). This is however (probably) not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can always type in the console. No one has to be listening. When you type in the console, the characters are stored in a buffer called a *stream*. If no one is reading the stream, the character just queue up. Calling `br.readLine()` draws characters out of the stream until a newline is seen.

Most consoles these days echo the characters typed themselves, and you can't generally turn that off, so even when you've stopped listening, the user can still type (pointlessly). If you don't want them to, and you think they probably will, the best you can do is output a message telling them not to (politely).